# what are gnome3 requirements?

Tags: gnome3

i know that i need composite graphics... but i can have it in software and still be faster then some cheap boards.

and i do have it in software (until ATI get their drivers to work with newer Xorg versions) and gnome3 refuses to start with a dull message about "not being able".

but there's no information on that message. no log files. no hint at how to solve it.

So, what are the exact requirements for gnome3 to run without complains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNOME3 requires 3D hardware acceleration otherwise it defaults to what is called the fallback mode.

See [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/FAQ#What_led_to_the_decision_to_make_3D_acceleration_a_requirement_for_GNOME_Shell.3F) for more information.

Comment: link doesn't mention what is required besides the obvious and non-descriptive :-/